# Make key value pair from select query

Tags: php

I am getting this response

```
{"id":"40","roomno":"118"}{"id":"41","roomno":"119"}
```

from my php function

```
/** 
 * Binding rooms to dropdown
 */
if(isset($_GET['beds']) && isset($_GET['type'])){
    $room_type = $_GET['type'];
    $number_of_beds = $_GET['beds'];
    $bind_rooms = new Rooms;
    $results = $bind_rooms->Bind_Rooms($room_type, $number_of_beds);
    while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
        echo json_encode($row);
    }


}
```

How ever i am trying to achive

```
 {"40":"118"}{"41":"119"}
```

Is there anyway we can get records as key value pair from database rather than the column name as key ? I've been trying to do this since morning :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo json_encode(
    array_combine(
        array($row['id']), 
        array($row['roomno'])
    )
);
```

or even simply

```
echo json_encode(
    array(
        $row['id'] => $row['roomno']
    )
);
```

Comment: Good answer. If $row is an object and not an array, might need `$row->id` and `$row->roomno`

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  array_combine() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\crudrooms.php</b> on line <b>87</b><br />